# Code for sitemap -- 'weekly.?

Tags: sitemap, xml-sitemap

I'm creating a Sitemap manually.

If I want to specify a url to be crawled weekly, is this the right code:

```
<url>
  <loc>http://wordfruit.com/</loc>
  <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
</url>
```

Comment: John made the code display correctly -- how do i do that?

Comment: also: do i put a forward-slash after every url entry in the Sitemaps doc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XML sitemaps don't really control how often the search engines crawl a page. It's merely a suggestion and based on experience and feedback from other webmasters it seems as though it is ignored completely.

Otherwise your code is fine. Below is the sample snippet shown on the [official XML Sitemap website](http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.php) for reference.

```
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
   <url>
      <loc>http://www.example.com/</loc>
      <lastmod>2005-01-01</lastmod>
      <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
      <priority>0.8</priority>
   </url>
</urlset>
```